# Transformation of field strength tensor in non-abelian gauge theory

Tags: homework-and-exercises, field-theory, gauge-theory, gauge-invariance, yang-mills

The field strength tensor is defined as

$$F_{\mu\nu}^a=\partial_\mu A^a_\nu-\partial_\nu A^a_\mu +g f^{abc} A_\mu^b A_\nu^c$$

where $f^{abc}$ are the antisymmetric structure constants and $A_\mu^a$ the gauge fields which transform as follows:

$$A_\mu^a\rightarrow A^a_\mu+\frac{1}{g}\partial_\mu \alpha^a-f^{abc}\alpha^b A_\mu^c$$

where $\alpha^a$ is infinitesimal and parameterizes the gauge transformation. For example a field transforms as $\psi\rightarrow U\psi$, where $U=\exp i\alpha^a T^a\approx 1 +i\alpha^a T^a$, where $T^a$ are the generators.

I want to calculate the transformation of $F^a_{\mu\nu}$ by plugging in the transformation of $A_\mu^a$:

$$F_{\mu\nu}^a\rightarrow \partial_\mu (A^a_\nu+\frac{1}{g}\partial_\nu \alpha^a-f^{abc}\alpha^b A_\nu^c)-\partial_\nu (A^a_\mu+\frac{1}{g}\partial_\mu \alpha^a-f^{abc}\alpha^b A_\mu^c) +g f^{abc} (A^b_\mu+\frac{1}{g}\partial_\mu \alpha^b-f^{bde}\alpha^d A_\mu^e) (A^c_\nu+\frac{1}{g}\partial_\nu \alpha^c-f^{chi}\alpha^h A_\nu^i)\\ = F_{\mu\nu}^a-f^{abc}\alpha^b(\partial_\mu A_\nu^c-\partial_\nu A_\mu^c)-f^{chi}\alpha^h gf^{abc}(A_\mu^b A_\nu^i-A_\mu^i A_\nu^b)$$

The last term cannot be correct, since I know that the correct answer is:

$$F_{\mu\nu}^a\rightarrow F_{\mu\nu}^a-f^{abc}\alpha^b(\partial_\mu A_\nu^c-\partial_\nu A_\mu^c+g f^{cde}A_\mu^dA_\nu^e)$$

Can you spot my mistake?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just turning my comment into an answer.

I haven't checked the algebra, but often in these kinds of calculations you need to use the [Jacobi identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Structure_constants#Example:_Lie_algebras),
\begin{equation}
^{}^{}+^{}^{}+^{}^{}=0.
\end{equation}
It would conceptually make sense if you end up needing to use it here, since the Jacobi identity is needed for $^{}$ to be the structure constants for a legitimate Lie algebra, which is necessary for $F^{a}_{\mu\nu}$ to transform properly.